# Adding Some Values in table using loop - R

Tags: r

I have a table and I can read the file. I want to add the values in the table under constraints that the addition of values should not be more than given value. What loop should I use?? 
Example, how can I read and add consecutive values.
Rank  Number
1.    10
2.    8
3.    9
4.    6
5.    5
6.    7
7.    4
8.    1
9.    3
10.   2

I have to add the values such that rank should be less but addition should be less than 10. The answer will be Numbers 9 and 1. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZq9C.png)

Comment: *"but addition should be less than 10"* Addition of what? I don't understand your expected output. Are these the entries from column `Number`? Or the row indices? Or the entries from `Rank`?

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Please show the code you've written so far and a variable with the expected output

Comment: @MauritsEvers  Addition of 'Ranks' should be as less as possible. But, the addition of respective 'Numbers' should be less than or equal to 10.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by *"Addition of 'Ranks'"* and *"addition of respective 'Numbers'"*. Do you want to calculate the **cumulative sum** of `Rank` and `Number`? You still haven't clarified on your expected output? What do you expect to get back? You really need to take a step back and explain clearly what you're trying to do and what you're hoping to get back (a `data.frame` or a `vector` or ???), and then walk us through the rules step-by-step on how to get there. At the moment, your question makes little sense.